# How can I fix this watering system?

Tags: watering

I have a computer-controlled watering system:

[image]

Recently, it started dripping from here:

[image]

the drips come out of the white region to the left of the large red bar. The white region is putty that I put in order to try to fix the drip, but it did not work - it is still dripping from under the putty. I tried to put more putty but it did not help either. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can never stop a leak from the outside.  Looks like mostly threaded connections ; unfortunately you may need to unthread a few things to get to the red handled ball valve. The valve is in the off position so turning off water will not be a problem. Once you get to the leaking thread , put a few wraps ( clockwise) of Teflon pipe dope tape on it and reassemble; actually all the connections will need tape as you reassemble them. Except the black tube going down at the end it looks like a compression or flare connection.